# Refining the result of mysql query result

Tags: mysql

I am using durpal 6. while retrieving data i got the following output:

```
| nid | fid |
------------
| 10 | 49 |
| 10 | 57 |
| 10 | 76 |
| 14 | 34 |
| 14 | 45 |
| 14 | 95 |
| 18 | 57 |
| 18 | 65 |
| 18 | 75 |
| 19 | 56 |
| 19 | 45 |
| 19 | 75 |
```

Now i want to refine the above output like this

```
| nid | fid1 | fid2 | fid3 |
----------------------------
10    | 49   |  57  |  76  |
14    | 34   |  45  |  95  |
18    | 57   |  65  |  75  |
19    | 56   |  45  |  75  |
```

Please suggest sql query for that..

Comment: You don't want that kind of SQL. You want to create that output in PHP.

Comment: Where do the results from the second example come from? you cant just magically create columns without any input of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better explain what you are trying to do. You can use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to return the fids as a comma separated list.

```
SELECT nid, GROUP_CONCAT(fid)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY nid
```

Comment: Around here we say thanks by accepting answers. Just click on the tick next to the answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 2 colum table you cant get 4 colums, but you can filter your results ofc.

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE nid = "10";
```

then you got:

| nid | fid |

| 10 | 49 |
| 10 | 57 |
| 10 | 76 |

and this way you can convert it in your programm as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can concat strings and in php explode it into array. Something like this:

```
SELECT nid, GROUP_CONCAT( fid SEPARATOR '|') FROM table GROUP BY id;
```

and in PHP explode `fid` by `|`

Answer (score 0):

In sql

```
SELECT nid, GROUP_CONCAT(fid) fids
FROM tbl
GROUP BY nid
```

will give display like

```
nid  |    fids
10   |   49,57,76
11   |   34,45,95
```

which you can format using PHP to your desired output